# i need help in "auto-complete for google places using text-field (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new in ios app development so i need help in "auto-complete for google places using text-field (objective c)"step by step process to better understand so please help me ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please elaborate auto complete for google places means?

Comment: when we enter city name in textfield ,in table view show all city name using  google api

Comment: suppose i want to find city ,when i enter "p" so start to find p related places using google api

Answer (score 1):

You should try TO look into google  developers site.

You can use this method :

```
- (void)placeAutocomplete {

    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:@"Sydney Oper"  //this should be your textfield text
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                              if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                return;
                              }

                              for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                              }
                            }];
  }
```

More info at : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Install the SDK : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

If you want to implement autocomplete for text field try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
    replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

  NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
  substring = [substring 
    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
  return YES;
}

- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

  // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
  // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
  [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
  for(NSString *curString in pastUrls) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
      [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
  }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];  // your table view to show the data
}
```

For autocomplete turotial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: Ok thanks sir, but i am using mkmapview and thats why when i am using this method it show me error use of undeclare identifier  GMSAutocompleteFilter

Comment: you need to integrate the SDK first and then implement this method

Comment: But sir after integrate this SDK i need to use google map but already I have used ios native map so what should I do??

Comment: you need to use uiview and give the file owner as GMSMap view. You should nt use appple map for this

Comment: Ohh then there is no option to change map???because i have  worked on it too much (using mkmapview).

Comment: YEs i know but i have to make it custom so thats why i have used textfield,its client requirement .so its not possible with textfield??

Comment: @TejaNandamuri hello, how could u help me how to search googleplaces using textfield in Swift

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API for iOS now ships with UI controls that make adding autocomplete functionality to your app easier. See the [Place Autocomplete Guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) for more info.